# Raspberry Pi Camera shows only a black image on second execution of OpenCV Python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, opencv

I'm trying to capture video with a Raspberry Pi 3B and a Raspberry Pi camera using openCV for some real time image processing. I would prefer to use only openCV for image capture to reduce the resources used by the program, which is why I'm trying to use native openCV functions rather than implementing the PiCamera module.

The application will capture imaeges in low light conditions, so I'd like to set the exposure time. I've found that I can set the `CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` property using openCV using the `set`, i.e., `camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, x)` method, where x is the exposure time in ms (when run on unix systems). Setting the exposure time like this only works if you first disable the camera's auto exposure using the `CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE` property. The documentation on this is a bit lacking, but I found various places online that says passing 0.25 to this property disables auto exposure, and passing 0.75 re-enables the setting. This is where things don't work for me.

On first run of the program (see code below) the camera works fine, and I can see live images being streamed to my Pi. However, upon restarting the application, I only get a black image, unless I reboot the Raspberry Pi, and by extension, the camera. I have tried turning the auto exposure back on before program termination, using `camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0.75)`, but that doesn't work. I have also tried the case where 0.75 should be passed to this property to turn auto exposure off, and 0.25 to turn it back on, but that also doesn't work.

The program is written for Python 3.7.3, on the latest Raspberry PI OS Buster, and openCV-python version 4.5.3.56.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
if not(camera.isOpened()):
    camera.open(-1)

camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1024)      # Sets width of image to 1024px as per SOST
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1024)     # Sets height of image to 1024px as per SOST
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0.25)    # Needed to set exposure manually
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 900)          # 900ms exposure as per SOST
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, (1/0.9))            # Sets FPS accordingly

while True:
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0.75)        # Sets camera exposure back to auto
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Note:** If replicating the issue on Windows platforms, the x value in `camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, x)` is the negative exponent of 2. So for example, `camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -3)` sets the exposure time to 125ms.

**Edit**: Fixed the exposure time in the code from 1000ms to 900ms.

Comment: I don't think you can set a frame rate above 1 fps if your exposure is 1 second. I think you are trying to set 1.11 fps.

Comment: @MarkSetchell ah, such a silly mistake. Unfortunately fixing that doesn't seem to fix the issue. The issue only shows itself upon successive executions of the code if the Raspberry Pi wasn't rebooted.

Comment: I *think* you have to set the exposure you want and then **afterwards** turn off auto-exposure because I think turning off auto-exposure *freezes* the current settings.